# When is NullInjector created?

Tags: angular

As per my understanding, NullInjector is parent of PlatformModule injector. While bootstrapping an application, PlatformModule Injector is created, When is NullInjector created?

Comment: Can you provide more details and also what you have tried from your end after looking over internet

Comment: As per [link]angular.io , when you bootstrap an angular application, i.e. 

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(ref => {...})

"The platformBrowserDynamic() method creates an injector configured by a PlatformModule, which contains platform-specific dependencies.".."The next parent injector in the hierarchy is the NullInjector(), which is the top of the tree."

an injector can only create childinjectors as per my knowledge. Then when is Nullinjector created?